# How do I remap a key to "fn"?

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac

New to macs, I found out how to remap other keys via "Modifier Keys" in System Preferences. This has let me remap "fn" to "command":

[image: fn key remap to command]

Which is useful as I'm more used to Windows keyboards where control (equivalent to "command" on Windows) is in the spot where "fn" is on the keyboard.

However, I'm unable to remap another key such as the (now useless as it's a duplicate) actual "command" key to "fn":

[image: can't remap command to fn]

Unless I'm missing something, has Apple made it so that only the "fn" key can be mapped to "fn", while all other modifier keys can have their functionality swapped around? This one-directional remapping seems like a strange restriction to have on a keyboard. For reference, I'm using what I assume is a standard wireless mac keyboard.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you might find Karabiner will do what you want.

Comment: I do understand why you would like the Apple keyboard to be more like a Windows one. But, with respect, I think is a mistake. Better to teach your fingers to do things the Mac way.  In particulate moving the Command key further out will make some command-key sequences more difficult - e.g. command-space which brings up Spotlight, or copy and paste actions..

Comment: Now you can do this, fn key is present in the drop down list.